# Where is monitor configuration stored in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: configuration, ubuntu-13.04

I have an `Ansible` script that runs through and sets up a new install of `Ubuntu 13.04`.  I would like to change configuration related to my monitors and switch mirror monitors off and configure dual monitors.  Where does configuration get stored for monitor preferences?

I know you can go to `System Settings` > `Displays` and uncheck `Mirror displays`. I want to have script or command to do this in automated way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actually an Ansible question, but indeed an Ubuntu configuration question or even a Gnome question.

Check ~/.config/monitors.xml for this.

These URLs have some more specific information:

```
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1780707
https://wiki.gnome.org/RandR#Storage_of_RANDR_configurations
```

Quote from the first URL:

> Edit this file
>
> ```
> sudo nano ~/.config/monitors.xml
> ```
>
> To fix the specific issue i had, edit the clone setting to yes
>
> E.G.
>
> ```
> <clone>yes</clone>
> ```

In your case it would contain a mirror tag or the like.

No Ubuntu desktops in my home at the moment, not tested :(